# How to get the text between the last occurrence of a pair of strings

Tags: sed, openssl, ssl-certificate

I need to extract text between the last occurrence of a word called "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----" and the last occurrence of a word called "-----END CERTIFICATE-----".

**Input :**

```
some other data above this line
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
a
b
c
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
d
e
f
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
g
h
i
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
j
k
l
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
some other data below this
```

**Expected output :**

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
j
k
l
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Output should include the -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -----END CERTIFICATE-----

**My Approach :**

I have tried the below command but it is giving me the output without -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- and -----END CERTIFICATE-----

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect localhost:443 </dev/null | sed -n 'H; /^-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----/h; ${g;p;}' |sed -e '1d' -e '/-----END CERTIFICATE-----/q' |sed '$ d' > mycertfile.pem
```

**output from above command :**

```
j
k
l
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I hear "get the *last* XYZ" I think "reverse the file and take the *first* XYZ": reverse the input, and have sed *quit* when the *first* "BEGIN CERT" appears, then re-reverse the data:

```sh
openssl ... | tac | sed '/BEGIN CERT/q' | tac
```

Since there's stuff after the last ---END line, try this variation:

```sh
openssl ... | tac | sed -n '/---END/,/---BEGIN/ p; /---BEGIN/ q' | tac
```

That only prints the ranges of lines bounded by the cert markers, and quits after the first one.

---

Another approach: use perl to read in the whole input, use a regex to capture all the BEGIN/END blocks, and print the last one.

```sh
openssl ... | perl -0777 -nE '
  @certs = m/^-----BEGIN .+?^-----END .+?$/gms;
  say $certs[-1];
'
```

Comment: Thanks for providing your valuable answer. I have updated the question a little bit. Your first command is printing some other lines at the end of the file which I don't want. I only want the -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- j k l -----END CERTIFICATE-----. Second command is doing the job but it would be great if I get the sed command for this.